# Mongoose: Sort alphabetically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `User` model

```
var User = mongoose.model('Users',
    mongoose.Schema({
        username: 'string',
        password: 'string',
        rights: 'string'
    })
);
```

I want to get all the users, sorted alphabetically by `username`. This is what I have tried

```
User.find({}, null, {sort: {username: 1}}, function (err, users) {
    res.send(users);
});
```

However, this does not sort the users alphabetically. How can I sort alphabetically?

***EDIT***: I got confused because I was expecting a "purely alphabetically" sort from Mongoose, not one where `Z` > `a`. Basically, I wanted a sort based on `username.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: That's the right syntax, so that should work.

Comment: It sorts the users according to insert date. And with `-1` inversely to insert date.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that duplicates the problem (complete with data)?

Comment: Try to execute `db.users.find().sort({username: 1})` in mondodb console and check the resulting sorting order. It'll help to identify the problem.

Comment: Alternatively: `User.find().sort('username').exec(function (err, docs) {` but yeah, your code is ok so something else is going on. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort

Comment: Got it. The sort function is just a little funny because `Z` > `a`. I guess I want to sort based on `username.toLowerCase()`. How can I do that?

Comment: I added to my answer based on the toLowerCase constraint.  For completeness you might want to edit your question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

EDIT: Per the comment the issue turns out to be sorting on `toLowerCase(username)`.  MongoDB doesn't have a built in method for complex sorting.  So there are essentially two ways to go:

1. Add a `usernameLowerCase` field to the Schema. This is the better option if you need to do this a lot.
2. [Perform an aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) with a projection using the [`$toLower` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/toLower/) to dynamically generate a `usernameLowerCase` field.  This comes with performance and memory caveats, but it may be the more convenient choice.

Original Answer: Here's a complete example that sorts correctly using the specific code from the question.  So there must be something else going on:

```
#! /usr/bin/node

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test');
var async = require('async');

var User = mongoose.model('Users',
    mongoose.Schema({
        username: 'string',
        password: 'string',
        rights: 'string'
    })
);

var userList = [
    new User({username: 'groucho', password: 'havacigar', rights: 'left'}),
    new User({username: 'harpo', password: 'beepbeep', rights: 'silent'}),
    new User({username: 'chico', password: 'aintnosanityclause', rights: 'all'})
];

async.forEach(userList, 
    function (user, SaveUserDone) {
        user.save(SaveUserDone);
    },
    function (saveErr) {
        if (saveErr) {
            console.log(saveErr);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        User.find({}, null, {sort: {username: 1}}, function (err, users) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            console.log(users);
            process.exit(0);
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: It's very surprising that Mongoose does not offer complex sort.

Answer (score 28):

This question and answer are a few years old, and from what I can tell there is now a correct way to do this.  Providing this for future searchers:

```
User.find().collation({locale:'en',strength: 2}).sort({username:1})
    .then( (users) =>{ 
        //do your stuff
    });
```

You could also index on `username` without case sensitivity:

```
UserSchema.index({username:1}, {collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2}});
```

`strength:1` is another option - best to refer to the documentation to decide which works best for you.

For the details of all this, [look here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/)

Comment: In my case, I had to consider diacritics too along with the case and `strength:3` is the option that I have opted for it.