# sorting alpha with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to sort via mongoose 3.6.20 and I am receiving some unexpected results.

I have a list of companies with a name. At first I thought that maybe it was sorting in a case sensitive way. Which based on articles, I expect was true.

I'm now using a virtual property to down case the sort field. However, I'm still getting unexpected results.

```
CompanySchema.virtual('name_lower').get(function(){
  return this.name.toLowerCase();
});
```

and when I sort

```
Company.find().sort({ name_lower: 1 });
```

I'm getting it in the following order:

1. company name
2. google
3. company name (yes a duplicate for testing)

I'm also outputting the value of my virtual property and it looks right. There is no whitespace or funky characters that would result in the 2nd 'company name' from appearing after google.

Using nodejs, express, mongoose.

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

---

**Update:**

Based on the information provided in the answers, I refactored my schema to include some normalized fields and hooked into the pre save event of my document, where I update those normalized fields and sort using them in all future queries.

```
CompanySchema.pre('save', function(next){
  this.normalized_name = this.name;
});
```

Next, is in the schema I use:

```
var CompanySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  normalized_name: { type: String, set: normalize },
  ...
});
```

Where `normalize` is a function that for now, returns a lowercase version of the value passed into it. However, this allows me to expand on it later really fast, and I can quickly do the same to other fields that I might need to sort against.

Comment: You can't sort on virtual properties.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Is there an alternative solution for what I'm attempting to do? Or do I have to store the name in a different field, but down case it before saving it to the document?

Comment: Can you write your solution as the answer? @user2787799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately MongoDB and Mongoose does not currently support complex sorting, so there are 2 options:

1. As you said, create a new field with the names sanitized to be all lowercase
2. Run a big `for` loop over all the data and update each company name to it's lower case form:

   ```
   db.CompanyCollection.find().forEach(
     function(e) {
       e.CompanyName = e.CompanyName.toLowerCase();
       db.CompanyCollection.save(e);
     }
   )
   ```

or

```
    db.CompanyCollection.update({_id: e._id}, {$set: {CompanyName: e.CompanyName.toLowerCase()
```

Please see [Update MongoDB collection using $toLower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423932/update-mongodb-collection-using-tolower) and [Mongoose: Sort alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279924/mongoose-sort-alphabetically) as well for more info.

Answer (score 3):

As of MongoDB v3.4, case insensitive sorting can be done using [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) method:

```
Company.find()
    .collation({locale: "en" }) //or whatever collation you want
    .sort({name:'asc'})
    .exec(function(err, results) {
        // use your case insensitive sorted results
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to put out that in this hook:

```
CompanySchema.pre('save', function(next){
  this.normalized_name = this.name;
});
```

You'll have to call `next();` at the end, if you want the `normalized_name` to be saved in the database, so the pre save hook would look like:

```
CompanySchema.pre('save', function(next){
  this.normalized_name = this.name;
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems to be more helpful to me. I had to consider diacritics along with the case so I had used `strength:3`.

[Mongoose: Sort alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44768732/7229801)