# How we can perform sort on ObjectId column in mongodb using mongoose with expressjs-nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

We are struct at one mongodb point which I would like to describe here.

We are using mongoose 5.4 and create a model like below :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({  
id:{ type: Number, default: 1 },
first_name: String,
last_name: String,
mail: String,
password: String,
dob: { type: String, default: '' },
gender: { type: String, default: '' },
profile_photo: { type: String, default: '' },
ethnicity: { type: String, default: '' },
contact_number: { type: String, default: '' },
user_type: Number,
address1: { type: String, default: '' },
address2: { type: String, default: '' },
area: { type: String, default: '' },
city: { type: String, default: '' },
country: { type: String, default: '' },
postcode: { type: String, default: '' },
business_name: { type: String, default: '' }, 
ip_address: String,
status: Number,
tag_line: { type: String, default: '' },
is_influencer: Number,  
wallet_id: String,
token_balance: { type: Number, default: 0 },
point_balance: { type: Number, default: 0 },
badges: [String],
membership: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Membership' }, 
transaction: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Transaction' }], 
property: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Property' }],   
reviews: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review' }],
created_date: String,
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

var propertySchema = mongoose.Schema({
id: Number,
property_name: String,
address1: String,
area: String,
post_code: String,
category: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }], 
category_id: [Number],
property_desc: String,
property_images: String,
slug : String,
user_id: Number,
business_key: String,
user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
reviews: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review' }],
status: Number,
is_claimed: Number,
created_date: String,
});

var Property = mongoose.model('Property', propertySchema);

var categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({  
id: Number,
category_name: String,
status: Number,
user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
property: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Property' }],   
created_date: String,
updated_date: String    
});

var Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

we are also using async-await for this project. we are fetching locations using below method to get location data as well User and Category.

```
sortClause = {};
sortClause.user=parseInt(-1);
let properties = await Property.find({'status':{$in:[1,2]}}).populate({path: 'user',
  model: 'User',select: 'first_name last_name mail contact_number'}).populate({path: 'category',
  model: 'Category',select: 'category_name id'}).sort(sortClause).skip(skip).limit(perpage).exec();
```

so when we get data in properties object after the execution of above line we are getting properties but as we are sorting by user's column of property model it does fetch data properly. It sorts on objectID and we would like to fetch on user's first_name.

I have tried by specifing  `{'user.first_name':-1} in sort order but it doesn't work at all.

When we sort on string or Number column it works fine, but here my expected result will be bit different, Here we would like apply sort on user.first_name (Here in above example user is the ObjectId column which populate Users data and I would like to sort on first_name column of user)
How can we get properties based on user's first_name column? Is there any suggestion for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: Sort alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279924/mongoose-sort-alphabetically)

Comment: @Shrabanee: Sorry to say that but i was looking for similar but my column datatype is ObjectId of other Model and i would like to sort on the result of that value(Result of ObjectId) when we done populate().

Comment: Have  your tried this `.populate({path: 'user',
  model: 'User',select: 'first_name last_name mail contact_number', options: { sort: { 'firstName': -1 } }})`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: We have checked using above method but this is not returning proper result.(At time of using sort in populate i have also remove outer sort but that is also not working.)

Comment: what result you are getting and what result you expect? please show some demo

Comment: This is our result at present :
 https://screenshots.firefox.com/9PI8UaL3QQAvFxuC/192.168.137.35       Here business owner column showing first_name of user.(property.user.first_name) we would like to short on this column

Comment: can you upload the current response JSON of the query you ran?

Comment: @Avinash  https://pastebin.com/ciiJ3eg1 (Here is our full json of our actual working code it will have so many other columns as well)

Comment: sorting on the populate should work for the firstName... and please comment with `@` to notify the specific person

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Here is my code where i am passing sort option but not working:
 let properties = await Property.find({'status':{$in:status}}).populate({path: 'user',
      model: 'User',select: 'first_name last_name mail contact_number'}).populate({path: 'category',
      model: 'Category',select: 'category_name id', options: { sort: { 'first_name': -1 }}}).skip(skip).limit(perpage).exec();

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: Here is my second try but not working 
let properties = await Property.find({'status':{$in:status}}).populate({path: 'user',
      model: 'User',select: 'first_name last_name mail contact_number'}).populate({path: 'category',
      model: 'Category',select: 'category_name id'}}).sort('user.first_name').skip(skip).limit(perpage).exec();

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: Here is my third try but not working 
let properties = await Property.find({'status':{$in:status}}).populate({path: 'user',
      model: 'User',select: 'first_name last_name mail contact_number'}).populate({path: 'category',
      model: 'Category',select: 'category_name id'}}).sort('first_name').skip(skip).limit(perpage).exec();

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet My mongodb version is db version v3.2.20

Comment: well It would be better if you update it to 3.6 or above

Comment: Yes, Let me try to upgrade mongodb first and check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178909/discussion-between-rushabh-madhu-and-anthony-winzlet).

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet : Finally below query works for Mongodb3.4 version.  
let properties = await Property.aggregate([{$match : {"status": {"$in": status}} }, { $unwind: "$category"} , { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "user", foreignField:"_id", as: "user"}}, { $lookup: { from: "categories", localField: "category", foreignField:"_id", as: "category"} }, { $match: { "category": { $ne: [] } }}]).collation({ locale: "en" }).sort({'user.first_name':-1}).limit(perpage).exec();
Worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation from mongodb **3.6** and above

```
Property.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": { "$in": status }} },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "user": "$user" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$user" ] } } },
      { "$project": { "first_name": 1, "last_name": 1, "mail": 1, "contact_number": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "categories",
    "let": { "category": "$category" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$category" ] } } },
      { "$project": { "category_name": 1, "id": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "category"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "user" },
  { "$sort": { "user.first_name": -1 }},
  { "$skip": skip },
  { "$limit": perpage }
])
```

Comment: Working fine but slice changes for Mongodb version 3.4.
    
let properties = await Property.aggregate([{$match : {"status": {"$in": status}} }, { $unwind: "$category"} , { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "user", foreignField:"_id", as: "user"}}, { $lookup: { from: "categories", localField: "category", foreignField:"_id", as: "category"} }, { $match: { "category": { $ne: [] } }}]).collation({ locale: "en" }).sort({'user.first_name':-1}).limit(perpage).exec();

Comment: Great!!! But there are a lots of benefits to use `$lookup` aggregation from mongodb 3.6 version